# in Axios how do i ensure my request doesn't contain cookies?

Tags: javascript, ajax, react-native, shopify, axios

I need to make a POST request to a Shopify endpoint (https://your-store-domain.myshopify.com/admin/draft_orders.json a JSON body :

```
const endpoint = `https://${APIKEY}:${password}@domain.myshopify.com/admin/draft_orders.json`

const requestBody = {
  "draft_order": {
    "line_items": [{
      "title": "Custom Tee",
      "price": "20.00",
      "quantity":2
    }]
  }
}

const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
}

async (callback) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        endpoint,
        requestBody,
        config,
    });
    callback(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
```

this returns a status 200 but with html of a login page instead of JSON payload.

I've posted on the Shopify forums to which i was directed to remove cookies from my request as they have recently disallowed cookies on POST requests.

I can't seem to find a way to ensure i'm not sending any cookies on axios. any help?

note: I have full read/write privileges on the endpoint and a GET request to the same address and with the same Authorization works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending this request from the client's browser? I would highly advise against this, as API credentials are very sensitive – anyone visiting your storefront can get your hands on these credentials and use them to access any data or perform any actions scoped to your application.

Comment: Technically, its through the client's app. this is for a React Native app. That is true and I have considered it, but I've locked down all sensitive operations. So if they really want to... At worst I guess they barrage me with draft orders ??